# Will the Nikon D3100 autofocus with the 50mm f/1.8D lens?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, nikon-d3100

I have the Nikon D3100 and was wondering if the autofocus on the Nikon 50mm f/1.8D lens would work with it.

I've read that the AF is not compatible with the D5000, and that the AF is rather [slow](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/nikon-50mm-f-1-8-focus) in general. With that in mind, having AF isn't a deal breaker for me, but I'd just like to know to help with the decision process.

Comment: I have the Nikon D3100 and was wondering if the autofocus on the Nikon AF-S Nikkor 35mm f/1.8G DX Lens would work with it?
also i am going to buy Sigma Zoom Super Wide Angle 18-200mm f/3.5-6.3 DC OS (Optical Stabilizer) does this particular lens support D3100?

Comment: Yes, autofocus will work with the 35mm f1.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Nikon](http://imaging.nikon.com/products/imaging/lineup/digitalcamera/slr/d3100/compatibility02.htm), no, you cannot.  You can manually focus, but no AF with an AF lens.

Comment: My response from Nikon support: "Thank you for contacting Nikon USA and we apologize for the inconveniences. The 50mm f:1.8 lens is an AF lens that lacks the Silentwave motor. Since the D3100 also lacks such motor, focus has to be manually done. No Autofocus will happen."

Answer (score 6):

Lenses without the AF-S (silentwave motor) designation will not focus on bodies without an in-body motor (any body below the D90)

Comment: AF-I (a noisy lens motor on some older lenses) will also work.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not, but I got a 50/1.8 D for my old Nikon D60 and it was quite nice not having auto focus, makes you take a little more time over what you are doing, unless that is important work that needs to be executed quickly,

Alternatively I would suggest the 35/1.8 that has already been mentioned, its a great lens at a great price and will auto focus on your D3100.